# Como hago para que me sume solo las opciones A y me desplegue el total y asi sucesivamente (son 4 opciones)

Tags: java, html

```js
<html>
<h1>TEST DE PERSONALIDAD</h1>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<script>


function Suma(formulario){
totalA=0
totalB=0;

nombre="";

for(i=0;i<formulario.elements.length;i++){
    if(formulario.elements[i].type=="radio" && nombre!=formulario.elements[i].name ){
        nombre=formulario.elements[i].name;
        grupo=document.getElementsByName(nombre);
        for(j=0;j<grupo.length;j++){
            if(grupo[j].checked){
              ((totalA+=parseInt(grupo[j].value)))&& 
(totalB+=parseInt(grupo[j].value));
            }

        }
    }else if (formulario.elements[i].type=="checkbox"){
        if(formulario.elements[i].checked){
                totalA+=parseInt(formulario.elements[i].value);




        }
    }
}



    document.form1.totalA.value = totalA;
    document.form2.totalB.value = totalB;

   
    
 
}

</script>


</head>
 
<body>
<form method="post" name="form1">
    <p>
<P>1 &nbsp;&nbsp;
Animado <input name="grupo_radio" id="radio_2" onclick="Suma(this.form)" type="radio" value= "1" />
Aventurero <input name="grupo_radio" id="radio_1" onclick="Suma(this.form)"type="radio" value="1"/>
Analítico <input name="grupo_radio" id="radio_3" onclick="Suma(this.form)"type="radio" value="1"/>
Adaptable <input name="grupo_radio" id="radio_4" onclick="Suma(this.form)"type="radio" value="1"/>
    <p>
<P>2 &nbsp;&nbsp;
Juguetón <input name="grupo_radio2" id="radio_2" onclick="Suma(this.form)" type="radio" value="1"/>
Persuasivo <input name="grupo_radio2" id="radio_1" onclick="Suma(this.form)"type="radio" value="1" "/>
Persistente <input name="grupo_radio2" id="radio_3" onclick="Suma(this.form)"type="radio" value="1"/>
Cómodo <input name="grupo_radio2" id="radio_4" onclick="Suma(this.form)"type="radio" value="1"/>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <p>
        total A<input name="totalA" type="text" value="0"  />
    
</form>

<form method="post" name="form2">

 <p>
total B<input name="totalB" type="text" value="0" />
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Soy nuevo en esto y estoy haciendo este pequeño codigo, quiero que me deje solo seleccionar una de las 4 opciones por fila y que al final me cuente cuantos A, B , C o D tengo en total , necesito ayuda. Aca dejo el codigo

```
<h1>TEST DE PERSONALIDAD</h1>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<script>


function Suma(formulario){
totalA=0
totalB=0;

nombre="";

for(i=0;i<formulario.elements.length;i++){
    if(formulario.elements[i].type=="radio" && nombre!=formulario.elements[i].name ){
        nombre=formulario.elements[i].name;
        grupo=document.getElementsByName(nombre);
        for(j=0;j<grupo.length;j++){
            if(grupo[j].checked){
              ((totalA+=parseInt(grupo[j].value)))&& 
(totalB+=parseInt(grupo[j].value));
            }

        }
    }else if (formulario.elements[i].type=="checkbox"){
        if(formulario.elements[i].checked){
                totalA+=parseInt(formulario.elements[i].value);




        }
    }
}



    document.form1.totalA.value = totalA;
    document.form2.totalB.value = totalB;




}

</script>


</head>

<body>
<form method="post" name="form1">
    <p>
<P>1 &nbsp;&nbsp;
Animado <input name="grupo_radio" id="radio_2" onclick="Suma(this.form)" type="radio" value= "1" />
Aventurero <input name="grupo_radio" id="radio_1" onclick="Suma(this.form)"type="radio" value="1"/>
Analítico <input name="grupo_radio" id="radio_3" onclick="Suma(this.form)"type="radio" value="1"/>
Adaptable <input name="grupo_radio" id="radio_4" onclick="Suma(this.form)"type="radio" value="1"/>
    <p>
<P>2 &nbsp;&nbsp;
Juguetón <input name="grupo_radio2" id="radio_2" onclick="Suma(this.form)" type="radio" value="1"/>
Persuasivo <input name="grupo_radio2" id="radio_1" onclick="Suma(this.form)"type="radio" value="1" "/>
Persistente <input name="grupo_radio2" id="radio_3" onclick="Suma(this.form)"type="radio" value="1"/>
Cómodo <input name="grupo_radio2" id="radio_4" onclick="Suma(this.form)"type="radio" value="1"/>
        &nbsp;</p>
    <p>
        total A<input name="totalA" type="text" value="0"  />

</form>

<form method="post" name="form2">

 <p>
total B<input name="totalB" type="text" value="0" />
</p>

</body>
```

Comment: Desde ya gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tenes que aclarar que es lo que no esta funcionando, y si recibis un mensaje de error cual es

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes hacerlo de la siguiente manera si podes usar Jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
    var totalA = $(".radio_a:checked").length;
    $(".totalA").find("span").text(totalA);
    
    var totalB = $(".radio_b:checked").length;
    $(".totalB").find("span").text(totalB);
    
    var totalC = $(".radio_c:checked").length;
    $(".totalC").find("span").text(totalC);
    
    var totalD = $(".radio_d:checked").length;
    $(".totalD").find("span").text(totalD);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>opcion A</label>
<input name="grupo_radio" class="radio_a"  type="radio" value="A" />
<label>opcion B</label>
<input name="grupo_radio" class="radio_b"  type="radio" value="B" />
<label>opcion C</label>
<input name="grupo_radio" class="radio_c"  type="radio" value="C" />
<label>opcion D</label>
<input name="grupo_radio" class="radio_d"  type="radio" value="D" />
<br>
<label>opcion A</label>
<input name="grupo_radio2" class="radio_a"  type="radio" value= "A" />
<label>opcion B</label>
<input name="grupo_radio2" class="radio_b"  type="radio" value= "B" />
<label>opcion C</label>
<input name="grupo_radio2" class="radio_c"  type="radio" value= "C" />
<label>opcion D</label>
<input name="grupo_radio2" class="radio_d"  type="radio" value= "D" />
<br>
<label>opcion A</label>
<input name="grupo_radio3" class="radio_a"  type="radio" value= "A" />
<label>opcion B</label>
<input name="grupo_radio3" class="radio_b"  type="radio" value= "B" />
<label>opcion C</label>
<input name="grupo_radio3" class="radio_c"  type="radio" value= "C" />
<label>opcion D</label>
<input name="grupo_radio3" class="radio_d"  type="radio" value= "D" />
<br>
<div class="totalA">Total A: <span>0</span></div>
<div class="totalB">Total B: <span>0</span></div>
<div class="totalC">Total C: <span>0</span></div>
<div class="totalD">Total D: <span>0</span></div>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda Leonardo, voy  a probar y te cuento.

Comment: Excelente , me funciono al 100% gracias amigo

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido! Saludos!